# Scheme - How to replace / change the element in certain position in list of lists

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am trying to change one value from list of lists and then "return" whole list in listh with another arguments. I am able to reach the value, but I don't know how to return list of lists with this changed. State consists of ((get-board state) (get-xycoordinate state) (get-orientation state)). Where get-board returs board, get-xycoordinate returns (x,y) and get-xcoordinate returns x positions.

```
(define (get-board state)
'(
 (0 0 0 0 0 0)
 (0 0 0 0 0 0)
 (0 0 0 0 0 0)
 (0 0 0 0 0 0)
 (0 0 0 0 0 0)
 ))


(define (put-mark state)
((+ (list-ref (list-ref (get-board state) (get-xcoordinate state)) (get-ycoordinate state)) 1) (get-xycoordinate state) (get-orientation state)))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution

```
(define (set-list xs i x)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) '()]
    [(= i 0)     (cons x
                       (cdr xs))]
    [else        (cons (car xs)
                       (set-list (cdr xs) (- i 1) x))]))

(define (set-matrix xss i j x)
  (cond
    [(empty? xss) '()]
    [(= i 0)      (cons (list-set (car xss) j x)
                        (cdr xss))]
    [else         (cons (car xss)
                        (set-matrix (cdr xss) (- i 1) j x))]))


(set-list '(a b c d e f) 3 'x) ; => '(a b c x e f)


(set-matrix '((a b c d)
              (e f g h)
              (i j k l)
              (m n o p))
            2 3
            'x)
; '((a b c d)
;   (e f g h)
;   (i j k x)
;   (m n o p))
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I needed!